# Hola Estoy tratando de ejecutar el comando ng-build --prod Ya trate de arreglar lo que me pide pero aun me sale el mismo Error y no se que hacer

Tags: javascript, angular

Al ejecutar el comando `ng build --prod` me lanza este error

> ERROR in src/app/shared/header/header.component.html(15,61): Property
>   'home' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
>   src/app/shared/header/header.component.html(18,73): Property 'home'
>   does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
>   src/app/shared/header/header.component.html(20,66): Property 'about'
>   does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.
>   src/app/pages/portfolio/portfolio.component.html(37,12): Property
>   'ProductosService' does not exist on type 'PortfolioComponent'.

```html
<header class="ae-container-fluid ae-container-fluid--full rk-header "><header class="ae-container-fluid ae-container-fluid--full rk-header ">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mobile-menu" class="rk-mobile-menu">
    <label for="mobile-menu">
      <svg>
        <use xlink:href="assets/img/symbols.svg#bar"></use>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <use xlink:href="assets/img/symbols.svg#bar"></use>
      </svg>
      <svg>
        <use xlink:href="assets/img/symbols.svg#bar"></use>
      </svg>
    </label>
    <div class="ae-container-fluid rk-topbar">
      <h1 class="rk-logo"><a *ngIf="infoService.info.title" [routerLink]="home">{{ infoService.info.title }}</a></h1>
      <nav class="rk-navigation">
        <ul class="rk-menu">
          <li class="active rk-menu__item" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="home" class="rk-menu__link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="rk-menu__item" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="about" class="rk-menu__link">About</a>
            
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        <div class="rk-search">
          <input type="text" 
          (keyup.enter)="buscarProducto( txtBuscar.value )"
          placeholder="Buscar..." 
          id="urku-search" 
          class="rk-search-field"
          #txtBuscar>
          <label for="urku-search">
            <svg>
              <use xlink:href="assets/img/symbols.svg#icon-search"></use>
            </svg>
          </label>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Ya intentaste dejar solo una etiqueta header

Comment: Ya lo solucione pero gracias ahora el problema es con http-server jaja pero gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: @JorgeDuran actualiza la pregunta o crea una nueva.